# Replacing cronjob schedule using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace `9 3 * * 3,6` by `shivam` using `sed` command.
`testcron` is the file name.

I am trying this

```
sed 's/"9 3 * * 3,6"/shivam testcron
```

NOTE: `testcron` is the file name.

Comment: Tell us what error you get, and improve title. (we wont do a better job because it is urgent to you, we will do a better job if you are clear about what you want).

Comment: As this is a `crontab` file, are you sure you want to replace all those fields with "shivam" -- or did you want to change the command that comes after them, on the same line?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to change it with shivam, i am testing something in the test environent. will implement something similar in my production environment., what basically i want is to treat 9 3 * * 3,6 as one character and get it replaced by another which in this case is shivam.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes have no special meaning in `sed`, they match double quotes literally. If they don't appear in the source text, remove them from the pattern.

Asterisk, on the other hand, has a special meaning in `sed` (it means *zero or more times*). To match literally, it needs to be backslashed.

```
sed 's/9 3 \* \* 3,6/shivam/'
```

Comment: Also, their `sed` expression is unterminated and there's an single quote missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found another 2 methods one by python  and by perl command

Python

```
>>> a="9 3 * * 3,6"
>>> print re.sub('9 3 \* \* 3,6','shivam',a)
shivam
```

Perl

```
@praveen_linux_example ~]# echo "9 3 * * 3,6" | perl -pne 's/9 3 \* \* 3,6/shivam/g'
shivam
```